# Bitnami stack (Drupal) Apache 2.4 Won't start after editing HTTPD.CONF

Tags: apache, drupal, single-sign-on, bitnami

I've spent a while looking for the answer to this so apologies if it's out there but I'm at my wits end.

I have a Bitnami Drupal stack on a Windows server 2008 R2 box which I am trying to add single sign on via the web server authentication module within Drupal. I have downloaded and installed this fine, however when I try to get Apache to load the mod_auth_sspi module by editing the httpd.conf file and adding the line:

```
LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
```

And adding the file mod_auth_sspi.so into the modules directory. As far as I'm aware this should do it, however once I do this and attempt to restart the Apache server it will not start up again. If I comment out this line it loads fine.

Is there something glaringly obvious that I'm missing? I'm performing all edits as an administrative account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post if there is any error in the Apache log file? Where did you download the module? Is that module compatible with Apache 2.4? There is a possible solution posted at https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4548 I hope it helps

Comment: Nothing in the log, apart from the shut down commands. It stops working as soon as I add the line to load the module, I've since tried another one (the one in the provided) and that's had the same issue. Thanks though!